# Rails generate error: No such file or directory - getcwd

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-spring

When running `rails generate` on a new Rails 4.2 project, I keep getting the error:

```
~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.0/lib/spring/configuration.rb:37:in `pwd': No such file or directory - getcwd (Errno::ENOENT)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The error is caused by an existing Rails Spring process running in the background.

You can easily solve this by running `ps ax | grep spring` to find the process id and then kill it.

There's an issue on the Rails GitHub about this:
https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/247

Comment: Ftr running `spring stop` is an easy way to kill such processes

Answer (score 9):

This error may also occur if you are working in a directory which was deleted from some other terminal instance.

Comment: Can you please share what would b the solution in that case?

Answer (score 2):

If the directory (or some sub directory Rails will work with) you are working was renamed or removed, you'll have to run

```
cd .
```

and then you can run `rails generate [...]`.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine the same problem was arising because spring server stopped responding.

1:- To restart the spring server type in terminal

```
$: spring restart
```

2:- Try running the generator again.